# Android SlidingMenu nullpointer on toggle

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, toggle, slidingmenu

I've implemented an SlidingMenu, I set it up with `SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu()` in the activity I want to use the menu. The problem I've got I want to toggle it via a button I've created on a  canvas. If I click these area on the canvas it will stop drawing and open the sliding menu - works until here. But then I added some content with an linearlayout and a textview in it, on clicking the textview the text changes (kind of menu to change some options). And after it changed once the next click should toggle the sliding menu again.
I've created the behind view's in another class, and triggered a method in the activity containing the slidingmenu, it looks like this:

```
    public void toggleSM() {
    Thread splash = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
                getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                animateButton.setLeftState(false);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    splash.start();
}
```

I added the sleep to avoid any problems caused by the sm animation or changing content, the aninamteButton is to trigger the drawing of the canvas again. But it throws a nullpointer exception. With and without animation of the slidingmenu.

EDIT:

The two classes I'm using:

```
public class Ingame extends SlidingActivity implements OnTouchListener{

private LeftMenu lm;
private SlidingMenu sm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sh = new ScreenHandler(this);
    fh = new FilesHandler(this);
    animateMap = new AnimateMap(this);
    ch = new CoordsHandler(this);
    animateButton = new AnimateButton();
    sched = new Schedule();
    lm = new LeftMenu(this);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);    
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setupViews();

    lm.setupLeftMenu();
    setBehindContentView(lm.getLayout());
    setupSlidingMenu();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gb.pause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gb.resume();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setupViews() {
    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getBaseContext());
    LayoutParams sizeP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    fl.setLayoutParams(sizeP);
    fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 153, 204));

    gb = new GameBoard(getBaseContext());
    LayoutParams fillP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    gb.setLayoutParams(fillP);      

    gb.setOnTouchListener(Ingame.this); 
    fl.addView(gb);
    setContentView(fl); 
}

public void setupSlidingMenu() {
    sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    sm.setMenu(lm.getLayout());
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    float distX, distY;
    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = e.getX();
            startY = e.getY();
            gb.movedDist.put("startX", startX);
            gb.movedDist.put("startY", startY);
            finX = finY = -1;
            gb.movedDist.put("finX", finX);
            gb.movedDist.put("finY", finY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            finX = e.getX();
            finY = e.getY();
            distX = startX - finX;
            distY = startY - finY;
            if(!checkUnvalidValues() && (Math.abs(distX) > sh.getTSize() || Math.abs(distY) > sh.getTSize())) {
                int rectDistX = (int) (distX/sh.getTSize());
                int rectDistY = (int) (distY/sh.getTSize());
                noMove = false;
                if(!checkEdges(rectDistX, rectDistY)) {
                    animateMap.animateXYDistance(rectDistX, rectDistY);
                    startX = e.getX();
                    startY = e.getY();
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            finX = e.getX();
            finY = e.getY();
            if(checkButton() == IngameButton.PP) {
                animateButton.changePPState();      
                break;
            }
            if(checkButton() == IngameButton.LEFT) { //WHERE I TRIGGER THE SLIDINGMENU
                animateButton.setLeftState(true);
                if(!animateButton.getPPState())
                    animateButton.setPPState(true);
                sm.toggle(true);
                lm.openLeftMenu();
                break;
            }

            if(noMove && !checkUnvalidValues())
                animateMap.tellCoordinate(finX, finY);
            noMove = true;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean checkUnvalidValues() {
    if(startX <= sh.getSideSize()-1 || startX >= (sh.getScreenWidth()-sh.getSideSize()))
        return true;
    if(startY <= -1 || startY >= (sh.getScreenHeight()-sh.getBottomGUISize()))
        return true;
    if(finX <= sh.getSideSize()-1 || finX >= (sh.getScreenWidth()-sh.getSideSize()))
        return true;
    if(finY <= -1 || finY >= (sh.getScreenHeight()-sh.getBottomGUISize()))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public SlidingMenu getSM() {
    return sm;
}

public void toggleSM() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void run(){

                getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
                SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
                sm.getAlpha();
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                animateButton.setLeftState(false);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     });
}
```

LeftMenu:

```
public class LeftMenu {

private Context context;
private Ingame ingame;
private AnimateButton animateButton;

private LinearLayout ll;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp;
private static LeftMenuPage page;
private static int buttonTextSize = 15;

public LeftMenu(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    ingame = new Ingame();  
    animateButton = new AnimateButton();
}

public void setupLeftMenu() {
    page = LeftMenuPage.OVERVIEW;
    setupLinearLayout();
    setupButtons();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setupLinearLayout() {
    ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
    llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    ll.setLayoutParams(llp);
}
public LinearLayout getLayout() {
    return ll;
}

private void setupButtons() {
    final TextView t1 = new TextView(context);
    t1.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
    t1.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    t1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    t1.setTextSize(buttonTextSize);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.weight = 1.0f;
    lp.gravity=1;
    t1.setLayoutParams(lp);

    String content = null;
    if(page == LeftMenuPage.OVERVIEW) {
        content = "Creation Mode";
    }
    else {
        content = "Back";
    }
    t1.setText(content);
    ll.addView(t1);

    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t1.setTextColor(0xffcccccc);
            switch(page) {
                case OVERVIEW:      
                    page = LeftMenuPage.CREATE;
                    t1.setText("Create Dwarves");

                    ingame.toggleSM();
                    if(!animateButton.getPPState())
                        animateButton.setPPState(true);

                    break;
                case CREATE:
                    ingame.toggleSM();
                    if(!animateButton.getPPState())
                        animateButton.setPPState(true);
                    break;
            }
            t1.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
        }
    });
}

public void openLeftMenu() {
    page = LeftMenuPage.OVERVIEW;
}
```

}

EDIT 2:

```
    05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity.getSlidingMenu(SlidingActivity.java:104)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at me.G4meM0ment.DwarvenSkill.Ingame$1.run(Ingame.java:234)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
05-10 15:14:53.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25064):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

StackTrace, as I already mentionen in some comments, getSlidingMenu returns null and mHelper (SlidingActivityHelper) causes this because it's null

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: @SankarV do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: which is the line SlidingActivity.java:104?

Comment: It's from the library: ` public SlidingMenu getSlidingMenu() {
  return mHelper.getSlidingMenu();
 }` I've already debugged mHelper type of SlidingActivityHelper is null, which is inizilized on create of this custom sliding activity stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
```

has to run on the UI Thread. Move it inside and Handler or if your are inside an Activity use

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     public void run(){
          getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
      }
  });
```

Comment: still getting the nullpointer, is it maybe because I change the text of the textview or because I use a linear layout? Because on changing the text the edge of the activity slided out disappears then.

Comment: can I see the line where do you get the NPE?

Comment: `getSlidingMenu().toggle(true)`

Comment: does getSlidingMenu() returns null?

Comment: seems to, I'll just debugg

Comment: yes it is null, I've checked a method from slidingmenu, seems that mHelper (SlidingActivityHelper) is null

Comment: strange.. did you call setBehindContentView ?

Comment: yeah, in `onCreate` of my activity, do I need to call it more than once ot the `menu.setMenu(View)` ?

Comment: can I see how do you init the slidingmenu?

Comment: I'll post the whole class (deleting some unecesarry stuff)

Comment: added methods and stacktrace to the question